# Accessing anonymous type variables

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I have this code:

```
object test = new {a = "3", b = "4"};
Console.WriteLine(test); //I put a breakpoint here
```

How can I access `a` property of `test` object? When I put a breakpoint, visual studio can see the variables of this object... Why can't I? I really need to access those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot use static typing for your anonymous class, you can use `dynamic`, like this:

```
static object MakeAnonymous() {
    return new {a = "3", b = "4"};
}
static void Main(string[] args) {
    dynamic test = MakeAnonymous();
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", test.a, test.b);
}
```

The downside to this approach is that the compiler is not going to help you detect situations when a property is not defined. For example, you could write this

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", test.abc, test.xyz); // <<== Runtime error
```

and it would compile, but it would crash at runtime.

Comment: Well, the thing is, I need the access to those variables, only to check if `test.c` exists... So I suppose this won't help me here? Anyway, nice solution, thank you!

Comment: @ojek You can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9956981/335858) then, it will help you check if a property exists.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the compiler support, then you should use a `var` and not `object`. It should recognize that you have an object with properties `a` and `b`. You are downcasting to an `object` in the above code, so the compiler will only have object properties

```
var test = new {a = "3", b = "4"};
Console.WriteLine(test.a); //I put a breakpoint here
```

If you cannot use var for whatever reason, then you can look into `dynamic` or [this grotty hack for passing anonymous types from Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx)

Comment: Okay, but I cannot use `var` here, because in reality, `test` is declared inside of my class, and it needs to be an object.

Comment: Then perhaps you should not be using an anonymous type.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the type is, as soon as you assign something to an object via `object test = new AnyClass();` you ONLY have access to the methods available to System.Object. Unless of course you cast the `object` instance back to a particular type but you can't do that with anonymous types

Comment: @ojek Yah, you should probably just create the type then. Anonymous types are not built to be passed around. I did update my answer to give you alternatives, though