# Newtonsoft Json de-serealization does not ignores nulls

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have following JSON

```
{
  "PROPERTY1": "vvv",
  "PROPERTY2": "aa",
}
```

That i want to deserialize with following data model class

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {

    }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string PROPERTY1{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string PROPERTY2{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public decimal PROPERTY3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string PROPERTY4 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public SomeObject PROPERTY5 { get; set; }
```

}

And use following serialization code

```
deserializedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(response);
```

As a result i expect to receive Class1 with PROPERTY1 and PROPERTY2,
Actually i get all 4 properties while PROPERTY3 is 0 , PROPERTY4 = null, PROPERTY5 = "".

Tried to pass serialize settings as 2 parameter

```
  JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {       
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    };
```

Not helped.

I want Class1 Object with no PROPERTY3 and PROPERTY4 and PROPERTY5 if they not present in JSON

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the issue? Of course you'll still have those properties they're part of the class. They'll just have their default values (hence `null` and `0`). The null handling is for serializing, they'll be ignored when writing out. If you want a dynamic type, use `dynamic` and not a concrete class.

Comment: Also, your JSON is not valid. Should be {  
   "PROPERTY1":"vvv",
   "PROPERTY2":"aa"
}

Comment: @Lloyd Typo :-) I want Class1 Object with no PROPERTY3  and PROPERTY4 if they not present in JSON

Comment: @AlexanderGorelik Then try `dynamic` as you can't strip properties out of your class adhoc - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net

Comment: @Lloyd this is the easiest way to handle de-serialization but i want solid structure and not documentation on the dynamic structure.

Comment: @AlexanderGorelik You can't it's one or the other I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public decimal PROPERTY3 { get; set; }
```

Your property is a value type. That is it always has a value. It gets a 0 and this changes when you assign. You have to convert to Nullable types to have that property becoming null.

You can also use dynamic. See here: [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)

This allows you to to use just the properties that exist. Other questions have answers that explain how to check for existance of properties: [How do I check if a property exists on a dynamic anonymous type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956648/how-do-i-check-if-a-property-exists-on-a-dynamic-anonymous-type-in-c)

Comment: Or use DefaultValueHandling.

Comment: @Sascha I want Class1 Object with no PROPERTY3 and PROPERTY4 and  PROPERT5 if they not present in JSON.

Comment: @AlexanderGorelik Provided a link how you can check for property existance on a dynamic

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want PROPERTY3 and PROPERTY4 if they are not in the json, you should deserialize like this :

```
deserializedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(response, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

I mean instead of deserialize to a class1 you should deserialize to a generic object. I'm just not sure about the porpouse.

Comment: In class 1 Property1 and Property2 are mandatory and other properties are optional.I will throw exception if first two are not present, and will check the other 3 to complete my validation process. I want to check the properties existence and not their value.

Comment: @AlexanderGorelik Even then you should use Nullable types or default value handling. Everything else is either reflection or dynamic programming which can be a serious performance issue...

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you should create an inheritance :

`Class1` with PROPERTY1 and PROPERTY2.

`Class2`, derived of Class1 with PROPERTY3, PROPERTY4 and PROPERTY5.

`NullValueHandling` is used only for Serialization purpose.