# Validating properties in dynamic objects

Tags: c#, validation, dynamic, scriban

I am using Scriban to render html templates for a mail service.
Scriban allows me to render html, using an object and a html template like the one below:

```
<ul id='model'>\n<h2>Name 2: {{ model.Username }}</h2>\n<h1>Message 2: {{ model.Password }}</h1>\n</ul>
```

I need to validate that certain properties exist in a dynamic object. In the example above, the matching dynamic object needs to contain a "**Username**" property and a "**Password**" property.

---

I have created a solution that works, but it is very hacky, makes me ashamed to call myself a developer, and will in **NO WAY** be a part of my final solution:

```
    private readonly string template = "<ul id='model'>\n<h2>Name 2: {{ model.Username }}</h2>\n<h1>Message 2: {{ model.Password }}</h1>\n</ul>";
    private readonly dynamic model = new {Username = "user1", Password = "pass"};
    public void Validate()
    {
        //Convert dynamic object to dictionary
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));
        //Regex pattern for finding properties in html-string
        Regex pattern = new Regex("(?<={{ )(.*?)(?= }})");
        //Properties in html-string
        MatchCollection matches = pattern.Matches(template);

        //Check if dynamic object contains a property for each match
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            var matchString = match.ToString();
            //Remove "model." from match. This should be done by regex instead.
            var property = matchString.Substring(matchString.IndexOf('.') +1);
            //Throws an exception, if the dynamic object doesnt contain the property.
            var result = data[property];
        }  
    }
```

How do i validate if a certain property exists in the dynamic object?

Comment: Maybe you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956648/how-do-i-check-if-a-property-exists-on-a-dynamic-anonymous-type-in-c#answer-9956981.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using the Dynamic object class, your model can inherit from the class. This will allow you to control what happens when you try to set/access members of dynamic object.

> The DynamicObject class enables you to define which operations can be
>   performed on dynamic objects and how to perform those operations. For
>   example, you can define what happens when you try to get or set an
>   object property, call a method, or perform standard mathematical
>   operations such as addition and multiplication.

See for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.dynamicobject?view=netframework-4.7.2