# Compare Property values of two json objects in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a two json objects like this below,

**Json 1:**

```
{
"data": {
  "firstName": "xxx",
  "lastName": "yyy",
  "age": "29"
}
}
```

**Json 2:**

```
{
 "data": {
    "firstName": "aaa",
    "lastName": "yyy",
    "age": "30",
    "location": "USA"
},
"meta": {
  "browser": "chrome",
  "ip": "999.999.999"
    }
}
```

How can i compare properties of json 1 with json 2 and return the bool value if values are equal ?

From the above example the **firstName** value is different in both json objects so the result will return bool value as false , otherwise it will return true.

Please help, thanks in advance !!!

Comment: deserialize, compare, return the result

Comment: Note that there are no such things as a JSON **objects**. They are strings

Comment: Please note that the `[asp.net]` tag is for ASP.NET (Framework) and `[asp.net-core]` is for ASP.NET (Core). I would expect them to be mutually exclusive, so seeing both is a little strange and can make questions unclear. They aren't relevant to this question anyway, so I've removed them.

Comment: Json 1 will change randomly for the next time , How can i deserialize it to c# object ?

Comment: What changes are you trying to detect here? All changes? What is the goal once you've detected them?

Comment: *"How can i deserialize it to c# object ?"* @Vicky since you're using json.net, check [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm)

Comment: Json 1 will comes from validation form which is randomly change , i have to compare that json 1 with Json 2 which is from database so if the property values are same then it should return true and allows user to access the application

Comment: Json 1 will change dynamically on every request, so i cannot create a c# class to deserialize it @Cid

Comment: @Vicky then, check [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm)

Comment: Possible dupe : [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)

Comment: On second request, Json 1 property will change like maybe it will not contain firstName property and only contains lastName and age , so i think deserialize and comparing is difficult

Comment: you can always [check if the property exists in a dynamic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956648/how-do-i-check-if-a-property-exists-on-a-dynamic-anonymous-type-in-c)

Comment: @Cid: I think it's *entirely* reasonable to refer to JSON objects. Would you object to someone using the term "XML element"? A "JSON object" is a parallel concept to that - and "object" is the term used in the JSON RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259#section-4. A JSON object could be represented in code without deserializing to a schema-specific .NET class using `JObject` in Json.NET, for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet I tend to disagree, since they are objects representations, not object themselves (although strings are objects), but this is just semantic about the Jon Skeet Object Notation :)

Comment: @Cid: They're entities referred to in the JSON RFC as "objects". So while referring to them *in the context of JSON* (rather than in the context of a programming language representation) I think it's fine to refer to them as objects. They *are* objects in that context. Again, do you try to "correct" anyone referring to XML elements? It's exactly the same, except that "object" is overloaded in this case where "element" isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Approach #1 - Using `JObject` from `Newtonsoft.Json` Library

```cs
var json1 = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
var json2 = File.ReadAllText("json2.json");
    
var jObj1 = JObject.Parse(json1);
var jObj2 = JObject.Parse(json2);
    
if (jObj1["data"]["firstName"] != null 
     && jObj2["data"]["firstName"] != null 
     && jObj1["data"]["firstName"].ToString() 
         == jObj2["data"]["firstName"].ToString())
{
   //condition is true
   Console.WriteLine("true");
}
else
{
   //condition is false
   Console.WriteLine("false");
}
```

Approach #2 - Using `Modal` & `JsonConvert` from `Newtonsoft.Json` Library. I have used [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/) to convert the json to c# class

```cs
public class Data
{
   public string firstName { get; set; }
   public string lastName { get; set; }
   public string age { get; set; }
   public string location { get; set; }
}
    
public class Meta
{
   public string browser { get; set; }
   public string ip { get; set; }
}
    
public class Root
{
   public Data data { get; set; }
   public Meta meta { get; set; }
}

var jObj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json1);
var jObj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json2);
    
if (jObj1.data.firstName.Equals(jObj2.data.firstName))
{
   Console.WriteLine("true");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("false");
}
```

Comment: If I were you, I would specify that you're using Newtonsoft.Json (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), but otherwise great answer.

Comment: @Mafii, thanks for the input. I will remember this when I am posting new :)

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla in my scenario json 1 properties will randomly change like on second request it may (or) may not contain firstName property . At that time i will get error while executing if condition .

Comment: @Vicky, then I suggest using model and Jsonconvert.. I have updated the post