# How to Deserialize JSON data in to Model Class in C#

Tags: c#, json

I am getting JSON data from the server like as below

```
[
{
 "Users" : [],
 "Validate":"false",
 "Employees": [
    [ 
       {
         "name" : "ram"
         "email" : "ram@gmail.com"
       }
     ],
    [],
    []
  ]
}
]
```

Now I want to deserialize the above data and  want to get user,validate and employees separately. for now I am using below code

```
 model mdl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<model>(jsondata)
```

Comment: please, tag the languange you want to use and add to the title (C#, Java etc.)

Comment: if you deserilize the `json` file to an instance of type `model` you should be able to Access `Users`, if any existing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));
```

Also you can use third party libraries for JSON, for example Newton Json.net: https://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: I am using Newtonsoft.Json namespace to convert json data, should I need to add Javascriptserializer also, or do you have any solution using newtonsoft json

Comment: Then you can check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038810/newtonsoft-json-deserialize, think you have 2 posibilities: 1. to use dynamic keyword to access the values 2. to create a new class hierarchy and then deserialize into it