# Deserializing a Json object

Tags: c#, json, parsing

Hi I have a little problem with deseralizing JSON.

It's json which i get from API

```
"{\"status\":\"ok\",\"categories\":
[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Name\",\"number\":0,\"clientsCount\":32,\"fields\":
[\"name\",\"surname\",\"tel\",\"post\",\"country\"],\"subcategories\":[{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Got\",\"number\":1},{\"id\":13,\"name\":\"Hipoteka\",\"number\":2},
{\"id\":14,\"name\":\"Samochodowych\",\"number\":4}]},
{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Name\",\"number\":1,\"clientsCount\":12,\"fields\":
[\"name\",\"nazwisko\",\"tel\",\"car\",\"car_model\"],\"subcategories\":[]}]}"
```

and this is how it looks like in PHP

```
array(
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Name',
                'number' => 0,
                'clientsCount' => 32,
                'fields' => array(
                    'name',
                    'surname',
                    'tel',
                    'post',
                    'country'
                ),
                'subcategories' => array(
                    array(
                        'id' => 2,
                        'name' => 'Gotówkowy',
                        'number' => 1
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id' => 13,
                        'name' => 'Hipoteka',
                        'number' => 2
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id' => 14,
                        'name' => 'Samochodowych',
                        'number' => 4
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 2,
                'name' => 'Name',
                'number' => 1,
                'clientsCount' => 12,
                'fields' => array(
                    'name',
                    'surname',
                    'tel',
                    'car',
                    'car_model'
                ),
                'subcategories' => array(),
            ),
```

I don't have any idea how to convert it. I dont need from this JSON fields subcategories but others are very important for me.

I have prepared some class but I do not know How to load to this class array of 'fields'

```
class Kategorie
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public int number { get; set; }
   public int clientsCount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The above array looks more like a PHP array.

Comment: What is posted as sample of "JSON" is not JSON at all. Please check if you've posted correct example OR update post to not mention JSON.

Comment: Sorry I post a php code I edited my question and add JSON string which i get from API

Comment: Do you really have a \ before every "? Can you post the raw json?

Comment: Yes I have. I do not understand how I can raw json? I receving this in that way: 

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }  

and the result is it this what I post

Comment: @Icet Use NewtonSoft JSON library and you can learn a sample [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038810/newtonsoft-json-deserialize) to deserialize json to C# object.

Comment: @Icet Also before deserializing replace the string escape chars: \" with a single quote: ' and then deserialize.

Comment: @SivaGopal thanks for advices! I will use them for sure.

Comment: @Frank the OP most likely copied the string out of the VS intellisense and that always escapes " chars like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample based on the Json you posted:

```
//Created MyObject to resemble the JSON object graph for easy deserialization
class MyObject
{
     public string Status { get; set; }
     public Category[] Categories { get; set; }
     //Similar to categories, You can create properties for fields, subcategories etc., as needed.
}
class Category
{
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
     public int number { get; set; }
     public int clientsCount { get; set; }

}
```

**Deserialization Code:** (Using Newtonsoft.Json)

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(jsonString);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I assume that's using the Newtonsoft library?

Comment: @Liath Yes I am using Newtonsoft JSON libray. Edited my answer to point this. - Thanks