# Strange Json to be parse in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am calling an api which is returning below mentioned json.

```
{
    "salarySlipItems" : {
        "\"0\"" : {
            "value" : "11000.00",
            "description" : "Worth Salary",
            "sort" : "1"
        },
        "\"2\"" : {
            "value" : "500.00",
            "description" : "Other Income",
            "sort" : "3"
        },
        "\"3\"" : {
            "value" : "1354.84",
            "description" : "General Allowance",
            "sort" : "4"
        },
        "\"4\"" : {
            "value" : "500.00",
            "description" : "Telephone Allowance",
            "sort" : "5"
        },
        "\"7\"" : {
            "value" : "-2000.00",
            "description" : "Other Deductions",
            "sort" : "8"
        }
    },
    "decimalDigits" : "2",
    "status" : "1"
}
```

can any body guide me how can i parse that in c# asp.net? What i believe  is **salarySlipItems** is a object having all properties. what are \"0\ \"2\ and so on..?

Comment: You can refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038810/newtonsoft-json-deserialize)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\"2\"` in this case is a key of dictionary. It is just an escaped `"2"`. In your JSON response all digits are presented as strings for some reason.

You can deserialize this JSON object using `Dictionary`:

```
public class Response
{
    public Dictionary<string, SlipItem> salarySlipItems { get; set; }
    public string decimalDigits { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class SlipItem 
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string sort { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you will be able to access it this way:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonString);
Console.WriteLine(response.status);
```

Accessing the dictionary item by key:

```
var item = response["\"2\""];
Console.WriteLine(item.value);
```

Enumerating through the dictionary:

```
foreach (var item in response) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} has a description: {1}", item.Key, item.Value.description);
}
```

Comment: `Response` also needs `decimalDigits` and `status`

Comment: @Rob Yeah, just noticed it :) Updated.

Comment: To expand on @Yeldar's answer - this is just a usual JSON object with properties that happen to have a number as their name. Since JSON objects are essentially just hashtables/dictionaries, and C# does not allow properties to start with a number, you'll need to use a dictionary to deserialize it.