# How can I parse such json string

Tags: c#, json

I receive a json string from webclient such like below:

```
"{\"1\": \"on\", \"2\": \"on\"}"
```

Now I should convert it into some struct and fetch the value,the point is the value is not fixed, it may be this:

```
"{\"1\": \"on\", \"2\": \"on\", \"3\": \"off\"}"
```

or this

```
"{\"1\": \"on\", \"2\": \"off\", \"3\": \"on\", \"4\": \"on\"}"
```

so my question is how can I parse such string. I need to fetch the value which is "on".

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038810/newtonsoft-json-deserialize

Comment: You need to deserialize into `Dictionary<string, object>`, since members in `C#` cannot begin with a number.

Comment: You r converting to json double times, show us the code where u r converting to json

Comment: Did the answer below help ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use JSON.Net (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json ) which is also available to NuGet.

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse("{\"1\": \"on\", \"2\": \"on\", \"3\": \"off\"}");
        var val = (string)obj.Descendants()
                   .OfType<JProperty>()
                   .Where(x => x.Value.ToString() == "on")
                   .First().Name;
```

This will get you first node with value "on"

Answer (score 2):

Dependency for this is :Newtonsoft.Json,Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

You can use following code to find the value of on.

```
 //var test = "{\"1\": \"on\", \"2\": \"on\"}";

//var test = "{\"1\": \"on\", \"2\": \"on\", \"3\": \"off\"}";

var test = "{\"1\": \"on\", \"2\": \"off\", \"3\": \"on\", \"4\": \"on\"}";

JObject obj = JObject.Parse(test);

foreach (var pair in obj)
{
  if (obj[pair.Key].ToString() == "on")
  {
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Both way possible. Linq or Query