# How to parse my Json Response String in C#

Tags: c#, json

This is the `JSON` Response I'm getting,I unable to parse,Please help me.

```
{
"features": [{
    "attributes": {
        "OBJECTID": 1,
        "schcd": "29030300431",
        "schnm": "UNAIDED GENITALIA LIPS DALMATIA RS"

    },
    "geometry": {
        "x": 8449476.63052563,
        "y": 1845072.4204768054
    }
}]
}
```

Comment: The json looks fine. What have you tried? And why doesn't it work?

Comment: Here's an excellent example for json parsing - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c

Comment: I want to get the value of OBJECTID i dont how,I tried some way but ,I failed

Comment: ... no one's going to talk about the genitalia in the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that might get you started [Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)

I like more the solution from NewtonSoft: [Newtonsoft JSON Deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038810/newtonsoft-json-deserialize)

You can use their JsonConverter to simply serialize/deserialize objects

Here's a simple example:
You first need classes that match the structure of your JSON:

```
public class MyCoolClass
{
   public IEnumerable<Feature> features {get; set;}
}

public class Feature 
{
   public Attributes Attributes {get; set;}
   public Geometry Geometry {get; set;} 
}

public class Attributes 
{
   public int ObjectId {get; set;}
   public string Schcd {get; set;}
   public string Schnm {get; set;}
}

public class Geometry
{
   public double X {get; set;}
   public double Y {get; set;}
}
```

Then you just use JsonConverter (JSON.Net) like this:

```
MyCoolClass tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCoolClass>(jsonStringThatYouGot);
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse a JSON you will most likely need a extern library like [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) or something similar.

Then you need to create a classes (a wrapper) with properties that match your JSON String and deserialize the string into that object.

When you create the wrapper class into which you want to deserialize your JSON String you have be careful to name the properties the same way they are named in the JSON String.

Example:

```
public class MyObject {
  public List <Feature> Features {get;set;} 
}

public class Feature {
  public MyAttributes Attributes {get;set; }
  public Geometries Geometries {get;set; }
}

public class MyAttributes {
  public int ObjectID {get;set;}
  public string Schcd {get;set;}
  public string Schnm {get;set;}
}

public class Geometries {
  public double X {get;set;}
  public double Y {get;set;}
}
```

Then just call the deserialisation function of the JSON library:

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(jsonString);
```

To access a property like the Object ID then you just call:

```
myObject.Features[0].Attributes.ObjectId;
```

Comment: thanks Bojan ,I have upvoted your answer thank you again,but I searching to get the GEOMETY class X,Y values with a objetct reference of MyObject?

Comment: var v = myObject.features[0].Attributes.schcd;                                             
 Show me error like Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type system.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<>.Any suggestions please.

Comment: try `myObject.Features.ToList()[0].Attributes.schcd` since the deserialization converted the List of features to an IEnumerable you need to call the ToList() function to access with [] operator... did you set the Features Property in your wrapper class as `List` or `IEnumerable` ?

Comment: Thanks thanks a lot bhojan you have saved my day,

Comment: No problem :), btw if u think others can benfit from this, you can accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using `dynamic` you can do like this

```
var json = "{ \"features\" : [ { \"attributes\": { \"OBJECTID\": 1, \"schcd\": \"29030300431\", \"schnm\": \"UNAIDED GENITALIA LIPS DALMATIA RS\" }, \"geometry\":  { \"x\": 8449476.63052563, \"y\": 1845072.4204768054 } } ]  }";

dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var objectId = obj.features[0].attributes.OBJECTID;
```

It uses [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), which can be installed with Nuget from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Be aware that this doesn't do any null-checks, and simply assumes that it's the first object in `features` that you want. But it's simple and doesn't require you to create any models.

If you want to use a more complete model I would go for the answer provided by [Bojan B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6345400/bojan-b) or [j0ey_wh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4695007/j0ey-wh).

Comment: Thanks for the smokes,This is the error i got  'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'features'

Comment: The example in the answer works and returns objectid 1. Are you sure you are using the same json as you posted?

Comment: Also. Make sure to set it to be a `dynamic`.