# How to use Newtonsoft JSON with child array element

Tags: c#, json.net

```
{
  "authType": "BASIC",
  "ipAddress": "192.168.210.152",
  "methodLog": [
    {
      "count": 12,
      "methodName": "getPrefixLicensee",
      "lastAccessTimestamp": 1475574521425,
      "firstAccessTimestamp": 1475563584777
    }
  ],
  "requesterGLN": "9501101020016",
  "onBehalfOfGLN": "9501101020016",
  "totalAccessCount": 12,
  "accessCountPer24Hrs": 12,
  "lastAccessTimestamp": 1475574521425,
  "firstAccessTimestamp": 1475563584777,
  "firstAccessWithin24hrsTimestamp": 1475563584777
}
```

How do i get the values in methodLog using Newtonsoft JSON?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Show what you have tried. Have you created any type of Object from the JSON?

Comment: Deserialize it to an object and then you can access the objects array?

Comment: There are thousands of similar questions. Just create the required classes, using http://json2csharp.com/ and then JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Newtonsoft JSON Deserialize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038810/newtonsoft-json-deserialize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create classes for your objects and use `DeserializeObject<T>`:

```
void Main()
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\pathtojson.json");
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    //Generic Linqpad output:
    result.methodLog.Dump();

}

public class MethodLog
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string methodName { get; set; }
    public long lastAccessTimestamp { get; set; }
    public long firstAccessTimestamp { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string authType { get; set; }
    public string ipAddress { get; set; }
    public List<MethodLog> methodLog { get; set; }
    public string requesterGLN { get; set; }
    public string onBehalfOfGLN { get; set; }
    public int totalAccessCount { get; set; }
    public int accessCountPer24Hrs { get; set; }
    public long lastAccessTimestamp { get; set; }
    public long firstAccessTimestamp { get; set; }
    public long firstAccessWithin24hrsTimestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: what about, i got 4 methods in methodLog, getPrefixLicensee, getParty, getItem, getGLN.   How can i slice the 4 methods and put them in one cell in a table?

Comment: Ask a seperate question for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it by creating class for child data and use that child data class as datatype in parent class and then you can use it..

like...

```
public class MethodLog
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string methodName { get; set; }
    public string lastAccessTimestamp { get; set; }
    public bool firstAccessTimestamp { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string authType { get; set; }
    public string ipAddress { get; set; }
    public List<MethodLog> MethodLog{ get; set; }
    public string requesterGLN { get; set; }
    public string onBehalfOfGLN { get; set; }
    public int totalAccessCount { get; set; }
    public int accessCountPer24Hrs { get; set; }
    public string lastAccessTimestamp { get; set; }
    public string firstAccessTimestamp { get; set; }
    public string firstAccessWithin24hrsTimestamp { get; set; }
}

public class SingleData
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

> NOTE:- You can change datatype as per your need