# C# Accessing JSON Stream Get.response Data in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am very new to C#and I am trying to contact a server and received data from the server. I can successfully receive the data, but I don't know how to access the object's properties. What I want is to display only the **SessionID** e.g. **"biRvqpChQZf7Cujy5CuW0PjU1R7gIp"**

```
    WebRequest LoginRequest = WebRequest.Create("xxx");
    LoginRequest.Method = "GET";
    WebResponse LoginResponse = LoginRequest.GetResponse();

    Stream LoginResponseStream = LoginResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(LoginResponseStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

    string TheText = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(responseFromServer);
    Label1.Text = TheText;
```

As is the outcome of TheText now is:

**"{\"utLogon_response\":{\"SessionID\":\"rP99mnHAFwI840xVJMDOJpcgmE2l6z\"}}"**

Here is the object "manually" from HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to deserialize

In this example RootObject should be your class :

*if you dont have a class with get;set; property, you can create it from [this](http://json2csharp.com/) website : http://json2csharp.com/

Just paste your json string in that website (json2csharp), and you will get all your property.

```
JavaScriptSerializer oJS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
RootObject oRootObject = new RootObject();
oRootObject = oJS.Deserialize<RootObject>(Your JSon String);
```

---

*step by step*

Suppose your json is :

```
string TheText =  "{\"utLogon_response\":{\"SessionID\":\"rP99mnHAFwI840xVJMDOJpcgmE2l6z\"}}";
```

And these are your class based on your json  :

```
public class UtLogonResponse
{
    public string SessionID { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public UtLogonResponse utLogon_response { get; set; }
}
```

then use this code :

```
   JavaScriptSerializer oJS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   RootObject oRootObject = new RootObject();
   oRootObject = oJS.Deserialize<RootObject>(TheText);

   var yourSessionId = oRootObject.utLogon_response.SessionID; //Done !
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit more please. I am very new to this. How would I now do "Label1.text = oRootObject.SessionID" or something like that. How do I now display the SessionID?

Comment: @Frank, I am not good with explanation, but I tried, review it, you may understand now.

Comment: I tried exactly your code but it seems to give problems. Here is a screenshot of what I have https://imgur.com/NDWzzdu

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Maybe just replace your "TheText" with "responseFromServer" just for it to align with my question code

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an object and then deserialize instead of serializing it. You can use [JSON.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) to deserialize them.

```
class Test
{
   public string SessionID { get; set; }
}

//after getting response from server
Test tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(responseFromServer);
Label1.Text = tmp.SessionID;
```

Below links might help you a lot:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

[Newtonsoft JSON Deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038810/newtonsoft-json-deserialize)

Comment: Even though your answer might be the best one, the lack of explanation caused me to rather focus on the other answer to find my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create an utLogon_response with string SessionId Property and to do : 
var text = Jsonconvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer)

Comment: Even though your answer might be the best one, the lack of explanation caused me to rather focus on the other answer to find my solution :)

Comment: No problem :)
When i published my response, the example of my code got truncated.. don't know why!