# Check If Variable Exist

Tags: c#, variables, try-catch

I'm building a program in C# using Visual Studio 2010. And was wondering if there's a way to check it a variable exist.

So basically, my `main.cs` is calling several other files (`file1.cs`, `file2.cs`, `file3.cs`, etc). Each of this files are very similar but some are missing some variables.

For example, `var v1` exists in `file1.cs` and `file2.cs`, but not `file3.cs`

In my `main.cs`, it's something like this.

```
string a = MyProgram.file1.v1;
string b = MyProgram.file2.v1;
string c = MyProgram.file3.v1; //will break here
```

I know the above code probably won't work at all, but that was the idea.

Is there a way I can check to see if v1 exists in file3.cs? Maybe something like this.

```
string c = VarExist(MyProgram.file3.v1) ? MyProgram.file3.v1 : "variable not exist";
```

I have tried to use try-catch, but the code won't even compile with that method.

**EDIT**

I know the variable doesn't exist, but is there a way for the program itself to check that?

In my main.cs, its looping through those file and applying the same operation. I want it to be able to do something like this:

```
foreach (file in files) //loop through file1.cs - file3.cs
{
    if (file.v1 exist)
        //do action1
    if (file.v2 exist)
        //do action2
    if (file.v3 exist)
        //do action3
    //....
}
```

Right now the program won't even compile, I'll have to create v1 in file3.cs and set it to null. This was the temporary solution because on other parts/function of this program, it's requiring v1 to NOT be in file3.cs (and no I can't change this because it's what the previous develop set up and I don't know the code well enough to change it)

This is a fairly big solution so I'm sorry I can't really post actual code. Thank you all for the time I really appreciates it.

Comment: its check compiler when you try build

Comment: No, that is a compile-time error.  You are not calling "files".  Store your data in a collection of some type and index by name, then check for existance data in the collection.  Exposing global variables amongst classes is a bad design.  Maybe you need to re-evaluate that first.

Comment: If this is a reflection question then this is a possible duplicate of [Finding the Variable Name passed to a Function in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72121/finding-the-variable-name-passed-to-a-function-in-c-sharp)

Comment: When writting the code, you should already know that file3 doesn't contain v1. You could just write down: string c = "variable not exist";

Comment: @the_lotus this is why Reflection exists. Maybe you are reflecting on a dll that you don't have in your position yet. A generic class or a method that handles generic classes

Comment: I bet you want reflection. Could you post a more complete code (an example of the contents of file1.cs, for example)? I think that what you have there is an static class with a public field. Anyway, something very similar can be done with dynamic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839598/how-to-detect-if-a-property-exists-on-a-dynamic-object-in-c

Comment: @AMR I agree, but it doesn't seem to be the case in this example. I might be wrong.

Comment: @the_lotus I think that is exactly what he is poorly trying to explain lol. He wants to see if a variable exists in a cs file that hasn't been defined. This is a classic case of reflection.

Comment: What it is you are trying to achieve utlimately ? Perhaps we could propose another way than checking if variables "exist".

Comment: @the_lotus Hi all, thank you so much for the time, I have updated my question and explain a bit more, hopefully this can give you guys a better understanding of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So... what type are those "files"? What I would really like to see is an example of one of those files. I see you said, it doesn't compile... I'll bet for this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11540889/402022

Comment: @Theraot the files are specific "rule" that applies to different users. It contains a class called userARule, which is a subclass of userRule

Comment: @sora0419 instead of checking if a property exists. The base class could have a DoAction() method that all subclass override with their specific action to execute. That way you'll only have file.DoAction();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments, you can add your items in a list like this:

```
var files = new List<userRule>()
{
    MyProgram.file1,
    MyProgram.file2,
    MyProgram.file3
};
```

This can be done because the type of those "files" inherits from userRule.

Now you can iterate with:

```
foreach (file in files)
{
    //something
}
```

For the check, do this:

```
foreach (file in files)
{
    var property = file.GetType().GetProperty("v1");
    if (property == null)
    {
        // it doesn't have the property
    }
    else
    {
        // it has the property
        // read it:
        var v1 = property.GetValue(file, null);
        // write it:
        property.SetValue(file, v1, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. So I ran into a couple issue. 1) No overload for method 'GetValue' takes 1 arguments. 2) Is it possible to set v1 in the original file? something like property.GetValue(file) = 'someString'; this is the variable that store a nickname

Comment: oh and I just realize it seems like reflection is only working for .Net 4.5. Is there a method that will work for 4.0

Comment: @sora0419 updated. In .NET 4.5 some convenient methods where added, the overload of GetValue with a single argument is one of those. I also show how to write the property.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to do this this way, you could use [`reflection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp). Be aware, reflection is slow though. You will be able to then use a try/catch each time you attempt to get a property's value.

What you call "variables" should be `properties` or `methods` defined (or not) in each of your class modules (file1.cs, file2.cs, etc.)