# Optional chaining for expando objects in C#

Tags: c#, razor

Here's my razor code:

```
<div>Creation date:</div>
<div>@Model.DynamicData.CreationDate</div>
```

`DynamicData` is an `ExpandoObject` on the `Model`. And if it does not have the `CreationDate` property I get this error:

> RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'CreationDate'

Since checking the availability of properties on expando objects is verbose, how can I use Optional Chaining on expando objects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect if a property exists on an ExpandoObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839598/how-to-detect-if-a-property-exists-on-an-expandoobject)

Comment: @SᴇM, that code is not `Optional Chaining` buddy. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Optional Chaining checks if the property is `null`, not if it exists or not. For example, you can write your own extension method to check if the property exists.