# Reflect on an ExpandoObject

Tags: reflection, dynamic, c#-4.0, expando, expandoobject

I have written a nifty function that will accept a `system.object`, reflect on its properties and serialize the object into a JSON string. It looks like this:

```
public class JSONSerializer
{

    public string Serialize(object obj)
```

Now, I want to be able to do this to serialize a dynamic/ExpandoObject, but because my serializer uses reflection, it isn't able to do it. What's the workaround?

```
public class Test
{
    public dynamic MakeDynamicCat()
    {
        dynamic newCat = new ExpandoObject();
        newCat.Name = "Polly";
        newCat.Pedigree = new ExpandoObject();
        newCat.Pedigree.Breed = "Whatever";

        return newCat;
    }

    public void SerializeCat()
    {
        new JSONSerializer().Serialize(MakeDynamicCat());
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reflect over the members of dynamic object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634858/how-do-i-reflect-over-the-members-of-dynamic-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this question is very similar: [How do I reflect over the members of dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634858/how-do-i-reflect-over-the-members-of-dynamic-object)

At least the answers should help you too.