# MethodInfo from ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, expandoobject, methodinfo

I know that it was asked for Reflection on ExpandoObjects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004965/reflect-on-an-expandoobject) before.

My question is a little different. I have static and dynamic functions which should be executed from some function similar to `object ExecuteFunction(string name, params object[] parameters)`.

I execute the static functions via Reflection. So the question is, if I can reuse the MethodInfo call and get a MethodInfo object from the ExpandoObject? Or do I have to implement 2 functions (One with `Action` and one with `MethodInfo`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get any `MethodInfo` for the dynamically defined methods on an ExpandoObject.
Dynamically defined methods are the same as dynamically defined properties, they just happen to be of a delegate type.

However, this delegate type contains a property named `Method` of type `MethodInfo` which you can utilize:

```
object ExecuteFunction(IDictionary<string, object> obj, string name,
                       params object[] parameters)
{
    object property;
    if(!obj.TryGetValue(name, out property))
        return null;

    var del = property as Delegate;
    if(del == null)
        return null;

    var methodInfo = del.Method;

    // do with methodInfo what you need to do to invoke it.
    // This should be in its own method so you can call it from both versions of your
    // ExecuteFunction method.
}
```

Please note that the first parameter is of type `IDictionary<string, object>`. `ExpandoObject` implements this interface, and we need no other features from `ExpandoObject`, so the parameter is just of the type of the implemented interface we need the functionality of.

Comment: So I'd have to use 2 functions... one with MethodInfo and one with Action or something similar... right?

Answer (score 1):

The opensource framework ImpromptuInterface (available from nuget), provides easy access to the DLR  calls that let you call methods by a string name. The only catch is if the method returns void you have to use [InvokeMemberAction](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#dynamic_Impromptu.InvokeMemberAction%28object_target,_String_Or_In) and if it returns a value you can use [InvokeMember](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#dynamic_Impromptu.InvokeMember%28object_target,_String_Or_InvokeMe). This allows you to invoke methods that are dynamically defined, and calls statically defined methods faster than reflection.