# How do I wrap an object in a dynamic object?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, expandoobject

Given an `System.Object`, how do I get a dynamic object with which to access any members it might have.

Specifically, I want to unit test an ASP.NET MVC 3 controller action which returns a `JsonResult`. The `JsonResult` has a `Data` property of type `object`. I'm populating this object with an anonymous type:

```
return Json(new { Success = "Success" });
```

In my test, I want to do something like

```
var result = controller.Foo();

Assert.That(((SomeDynamicType)result.Data).Success, Is.EqualTo("Success"));
```

How is this done?

**UPDATE**
Though `result.Data` is of type `object`, inspecting it in the Watch window shows it has the following type:

```
{
    Name = "<>f__AnonymousType6`1" 
    FullName = "<>f__AnonymousType6`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"
} 
System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
```

Comment: What is the type of `result.Data`? Is it `new {...}` or the `Json` object or a `string` or...? *It should work assuming result.Data is what is expected*, here is a LINQPad example that does work: `var x = new { X = 1 }; var y = (dynamic)x;
((object)y.X).Dump();`.

Comment: @pst, `result.Data` is typed as `object` but it is populated by the `new {Success = "Success"}` being passed into the `return Json(...)` call.

Comment: Can see how the `JsonResult` is created? I see a `Json` wrapping the `new {}`... (what is the full `Json` type used?) Try to break on the exception and view the data/type info of the object in Data. Compare the `new {...}` object (by reference as well) and the object in Data.

Comment: Have a look at the discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634858/how-do-i-reflect-over-the-members-of-dynamic-object

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous types are internal, and the dynamic api's are called by the compiler in such a way to respect that protection. Using ImpromptuInterface, open source available in nuget, it has an [ImpromptuGet](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageDynamic#ImpromptuGet) class that will allow you to wrap your anonymous type and will use the dynamic api's as if from the anonymous type itself so you don't have the protection issue.

```
//using ImpromptuInterface.Dynamic
Assert.That(ImpromptuGet.Create(result.Data).Success, Is.EqualTo("Success"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an implementation of `DynamicObject`:

```
public class MyDynamic: DynamicObject
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public MyDynamic(object initialData)
    {
        if (initialData == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("initialData");
        var type = initialData.GetType();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
        {
            dictionary.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(initialData, null));
        }
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        dictionary.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        dictionary[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }

}
```

and then:

```
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var json = new {Success = "Ok"};
        dynamic dynObj = new MyDynamic(json);
        Assert.AreEqual(dynObj.Success, "Ok");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are trying to inspect an object which is Json, why not run result.Data through JsonValueProviderFactory, and then search the backing store for the key named "Success"?