# dynamic as a return type

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic

I'm in a situation where I need to return an object of an anonymous type from a method, is it a good idea to use `dynamic` as a return type? what considerations to take?

```
public dynamic MyMethod()
{
    // process and return the object of an anonymous type
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it has sense *If you "guarantee" that you'll always return an object with some characteristics* , with an `Id` for example (ignoring that perhaps it would be better to use an Interface)

```
public dynamic MyMethod()
{
    var temp = new ExpandoObject();
    temp.Id = 5;
    return temp;
}

Console.WriteLine(MyMethod().Id);
```

So if you guarantee that all your objects can `Turn Left-Right` but you don't guarantee if they are airplanes, cars, motos, boats. (so it's good if you are doing [Duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) `When I see a bird that walks like a duck and swims like a duck and quacks like a duck, I call that bird a duck.`)

Note that if you then need to reflect on your objects, it can become ugly: [How do I reflect over the members of dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2634858/613130)

Comment: No I don't want to reflect, I just want to return it through JSON (the method is an MVC action method actually) and forget about it. I'm using an interface for the holder class though.

Comment: @LordCover Then it shouldn't be really important. The JSON parser will have to reflect on the object.

Comment: @LordCover Good luck with dates? :-) (I'm not kidding. Try going back and forth with the dates... Sometimes bad things happen. Check the `DateTime.Kind` after the "forth" (so from Javascript to C#))

Comment: the anonymous object is a list of 2 integers in the anonymous type, well it could be List<int, int> (How come I didn't notice that). but to answer you, there is no dates within the object.

Comment: @LordCover It could have been a `List<Tuple<int, int>>` or a `List<int[]>`, not a `List<int, int>`

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't make any sence, you can return `object` with the same effect.

P.S.: Also anonymous types are not that good as return types.

Comment: Specifically not good as return types because they internal. And if you return outside of assembly boundaries, you'll get runtime binding errors. ExpandoObject is a better alternative to anonymous when returning dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a dynamic object does have the benifit of allowing you to access the properties from the anonmymous type without using reflection (albeit without intellisense). If you take this approach you need to make sure that the properties on the anonymous type match what you are accessing on the dynamic object. Otherwise you will get runtime errors

However, I would suggest you consider returning a concrete type instead