# Get property of dynamic object by string

Tags: c#

I have this:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> operations;
foreach(var row in operations)
{
  // this works, myElementName is a db field
  var tmp = row.myElementName;
  // this is what I wish:
  string myField ="myElementName";
  var tmp_error = row.getProperty(myField);
}
```

Is it possible? I've tried with reflection but it did not work..

not work 'cause getProperty doesn't exists and using reflection retrieves null values

Thanks!

Comment: If you are going to use reflection, why bother with dynamic? Just a question while I research an answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634858/how-do-i-reflect-over-the-members-of-dynamic-object

Comment: Just saying "doesn't work" really doesn't help us - what exactly did you try, and what exactly happened?

Comment: thanks @SteveMitcham! it works with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2634969