# How to Get Properties key names from a List in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

If I have a list such as :

```
var ListCommandQuery = new List<dynamic> { }; 

ListCommandQuery.Add( 
new { User_ID = "4", User_Name = "jhony" ,    Mobile_Phone = 054175548999} );
```

and i want to print only the Properties key names not the values 
 so the result will show me :

```
User_ID 
User_Name 
Mobile_Phone
```

instead of :

```
4
jhony
054175548999
```

How that can be done ?

Comment: You need to use reflection

Comment: The lazy in me says, reference JSON.NET and use the built-in ability therein, to cast a `dynamic` into a `JObject`. A `JObject`, of course, will nicely give you a `Dictionary<string, object>` interface to all the field names via the `.ToObject` method.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634858/how-do-i-reflect-over-the-members-of-dynamic-object.

Comment: @code4life ,@Peter Bons : Thank you guys for suggestions and explanations :) and the solution that works for me is the one posted by "Filip Cordas" down here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332870/get-key-names-from-a-list/42332977#42332977

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using anonymous types you need the type definition

```
foreach (var item in listCommandQuery)
{
     foreach (var prop in item.GetType().GetProperties())
     {
              Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
     }
}
```

In an anonymous object the names are not keys like in a DynamicObject but actual Properties. The Compiler creates an actual class for you in the background. Unlike ExpandoObject where the object is an IDictonery

Comment: thank you very much , it works perfect 
and short codes are always my favor  .
and the description was good to understand the reasons behind , thumb up for you :)