# Updating property of deserialised JSON object (without a defined deser type)

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I'm getting some JSON as a string and storing it as such:

```
private static List<object> history = new List<object>();

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(parsedData);
history.Add(data);
```

The JSON data looks something like this:

```
{ id: 12, data: 'my data' }
```

I'd like to add another method that iterates through the `history` list, finds an item by its ID and updates it.

What's the best way to access properties on objects like this?

Comment: Probably deserialize to `dynamic` so you can use [reflection to get property names or do whatever dynamic stuff you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634858/how-do-i-reflect-over-the-members-of-dynamic-object).

Comment: use a legitimate type that represents the data instead of `object`

Comment: make `history` be `List<dynamic>` then do `history.Where(i => i.id == 12);`.  For more see [Querying JSON with dynamic](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm).   But this will throw an exception when history items don't have an id, so using an explicit type (or even a `JToken` with its dictionary methods) would be better.

Answer (score 1):

If the incoming JSON string always has the same fields, you can serialize it to a defined class/type.

```
public class JsonHistory
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string data { get; set; }
}

List<JsonHistory> history = new List<JsonHistory>();

var histData= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonHistory>(parsedData);
history.Add(histData);
```

You can also then use linq to find any matches you are looking for:

```
var matches = history.Where(x => x.id == 10).Select(x => x.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dynamic` instead of `object`, because it is easier to use properties rather than `object`

```
List<dynamic> history = new List<dynamic>();
string parsedData = "{ id: 12, data: 'my data' }";
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(parsedData);
history.Add(data);
history.Add(data);
foreach (var o in history)
{
    o.id = 13;
}
```

Also, I strongly suggest you to create a class and use it as known type. That will give you intellisense and definitely you will need that further.

Answer (score 0):

The [JSON.NET documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) has the following approach, that I would also suggest using:

First - deserialise to a sensible type (anonymous is fine)

```
var json = "{id: 12, data: 'my data'}";
var definition = new { Id = 0, Data = "" }
var deserialised = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, definition);
```

Second - you've got your first item, so you can "trick" the compiler into letting you use the anonymous type in a list:

```
var history = (new[] { deserialised }).ToList();
```

You can then shove any other deserialised instances into that list.

Now you can do your filtering:

```
var itemImLookingFor = history.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 10);
```

Once you've then got the item, you can just update it:

```
itemImLookingFor.Data = itemImLookingFor.Data.ToUpperCase()
```

I'd recommend reading [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135160/shortcomings-of-using-dynamic-types-in-c) as it explains some of the shortcomings inherent in using the `dynamic` keyword; it's not a bad thing to do, it just has its place.

For this scenario, JSON.NET gives you all the tools you need to either deserialise to a type of your own defining (e.g. write a class that mirrors the JSON, or to an anonymous type like I've done here).

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to either deserialize to a custom class or to deserialize to [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) which would allow you to iterate over its properties like using reflection. Both require a lot of typing.

But you can use a clever little trick and get all the benefits of a strong type without having to write the class.

### Use an anonymous duck type

Add this method to your library somewhere:

```
static public T JsonDeserialize<T>(string input, T template)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(input);
}
```

Once you have this in place, you can use it to duck-type the JSON (i.e. get the compiler to infer an anonymous type) by supplying an example instance. This allows you to use anonymous types instead of typing up a custom class.

So for example, to get the row with ID 12, you do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


public class Program
{
    static public T JsonDeserialize<T>(string input, T example)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(input);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        //Sample data with two records
        const string input = @"[ { 'id' : 12, 'data' : 'MyData' }, { 'id' : 13, 'data' : 'Another record' } ]";

        //Create an example instance so the compiler can use its anonymous type
        var example = new []
                {
                    new { id = default(int), data = default(string) }
                };


        //Pass the example as argument 2 so that the compiler can infer T. The argument itself isn't used for anything.
        var list = JsonDeserialize(input, example);

        //Now we have a strongly-typed list, without having to write a class

        //We can use LINQ or anything else that needs a strong type
        foreach ( var o in list.Where( a => a.id == 12) )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o.id);
            Console.WriteLine(o.data);  //Intellisense works here
        }


    }
}
```

Output:

```
12
MyData
```

[Working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pVti9h).

Comment: This is amazing, I had no idea you could do this.

Comment: @Donut indeed you can, JSON.NET even has a built in method for it `DeserializeAnonymousType(json,example)`