# How can I find out if a dynamic property exists in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am iterating through some Active Directory PrincipalSearcher Principal results using the code below.  In my foreach loop where I am assigning result properties to my _user object I can break in debug and see a result.EmailAddress value.  When I try to assign result.EmailAddress to _user.EmailAdress the code will not even compile.  I'm guessing EmailAddress is a dynamic property of result.  Is there a way to check for this property so I can add the users AD email address to my _user object?

```
 private static void GetAllActiveDirectoryUsers()
    {
        PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(
        ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName);

        UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(context);


        // create a principal searcher for running a search operation
        PrincipalSearcher pS = new PrincipalSearcher(user);

        // run the query
        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = pS.FindAll();

        foreach (Principal result in results)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(result.DisplayName);
            Console.ReadKey();

            User _user = new User();

            _user.Description = result.Description;
            _user.DisplayName = result.DisplayName;
            _user.DistinguishedName = result.DistinguishedName;
            _user.Guid = result.Guid ?? null;
            _user.Name = result.Name;
            _user.Sid = result.Sid?.ToString();

            Users.Add(_user);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634858/how-do-i-reflect-over-the-members-of-dynamic-object

Comment: You need to get the underlying [`DirectoryEntry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry(v=vs.110).aspx) using [`_user.GetUnderlyingObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.getunderlyingobject(v=vs.110).aspx). You can then iterate through the properties or sub-objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a dynamic property. `EmailAddress` is a property of the `UserPrincipal` class, which inherits from `Principal`. Your `result` is actually of type `UserPrincipal`, which is why you see the property when you debug, but you are accessing it as type `Principal`, which doesn't have a property called `EmailAddress`, so it is not available to you in your code.

If you want access to the `EmailAddress` property, you need to cast your `result` to `UserPrincipal`. Since you are sure all of your results will be user objects, then you can do that in the `foreach`:

```
foreach (UserPrincipal result in results)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to get the `DirectoryEntry` object from the `Principal` and query it's properties.

Something like this - assuming email is stored in the 'mail' attribute.

```
 var directoryEntry = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
 if (directoryEntry != null && directoryEntry.Properties.Contains("mail"))
 {
    _user.EmailAddress = directoryEntry.Properties[property].Value.ToString();
 }
```

Here is an extension method that uses the above.  It simply takes a string for the attribute that you are searching for.

```
public static string GetPropertyValue(this Principal principal, string property)
{
    var directoryEntry = principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
    if (directoryEntry != null && directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(property))
    {
        return directoryEntry.Properties[property].Value.ToString();
    }

    return null;
}
```