# Generic method to parse json of any structure (nth depth) c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Have to write a generic method which will take json of any structure and add new properties to each element with data

Structure # 1, (Person)

Input Json data,

```
 {'name':'sam', 'age': 12}
```

Expected output,

```
{'name':'sam', 'name_xyz': 'Rob', 'age': 12, 'age_xyz': 15}
```

Structure # 2, (Person with address)

Input json data,

```
{ 'name': 'sam', address : { 'city': 'fishers', 'zip': 23456 } }
```

Expected output,

```
{'name': 'sam', 'name_xyz': 'rob', address : { 'city': 'fishers', 'city_xyz': 'fishers', 'zip': 23456, 'zip_xyz': 678768} }
```

Structure # 3 (Person's)

Input json data,

```
[{'name': 'sam'}, {'name':'rex'}]
```

Expected Output,

```
[{'name': 'sam', 'name_xyz': 'felix'}, {'name':'rex', 'name_xyz' : 'bob'}]
```

I have something for defined model using NewtonSoft, but I need generic method to parse and evaluate any type of json data.

```
var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modelData);
var jArray = JArray.Parse(jsonData) as JArray;
dynamic persons = jArray;
foreach (dynamic person in persons)
{
 var name = person.name;
 var newname = Getnewname(name);
 person.Add(new JProperty("name_xyz", newname));

 var age = person.age;
 var newage = GetnewAge(age);
 person.Add(new JProperty("age_xyz", newage));
}
var result = persons.ToString();
```

Things to consider,

1. Look for each node, determine if it is array or object
2. Found object, create new object at same level with same property post fix '_xyz'
3. Found Array, loop through each object and same step 2
4. It will be nth level depth

Comment: I am not clear what the question is in this post.

Comment: want to read json of any type/structure then add new properties to each of existing properties with naming convention 'existingproperty_xyz' with new value

Comment: From your Structure #2 expected output, it doesn't seem like you are creating a new object at the same level as you stated in Consideration #2. More like replacing it or just traversing into it and adding more properties. Other than that, you can achieve this using some recursive method.

Comment: Yes correct not new object, just traversing into and add more new properties. I am looking for that recursive function.

Comment: @alans correct just traversing and adding more properties.

Comment: Something like this is not readily available in C# or NewtonSoft.JSON. You can write your own logic which will use reflection to identify the existing properties and create new properties.  You can read about reflection [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection). Also you can read about using reflection on dynamic objects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634858/how-do-i-reflect-over-the-members-of-dynamic-object)

Comment: How do you determine what the value should be for the new properties that are added?

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, what is the use case for this magical method?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar situation and I solved it using a "*nested dictionary*" approach. While it is always a pleasure to work in the comfort zone of strongly typed entities, there are times when creating **C#** classes might get too cumbersome. This was my situation.

Treat the entire JSON like a dictionary where one or more keys might store another Dictionary. And this might continue several levels deep.  The method *Jobject.Parse* worked for me. The *JObject* works like a key-value collection and you can recursively retrieve more *JObject* instances as you traverse deeper.

**Newtonsoft reference - flat dictionary**
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm

This will NOT work very well with a nested structure like yours.

**Newtonsoft code snippet - parsing as a JObject**

```
string json="[{'name': 'sam', 'name_xyz': 'felix'}, {'name':'rex', 'name_xyz' : 'bob'}]"
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
```

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonObject.htm

**Newtonsoft reference - JObject**
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm

**More examples on using JObject as opposed to hard typing**

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm