# How to get property name and value from C# Dynamic object when using CsvHelper?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am using CsvHelper to read CSV files into Dynamic C# object and I would like to iterate the `List<dynamic>` using `foreach` and get property names and values.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\Temp\\CSVTest.csv");

List<dynamic> dynObj;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    dynObj = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList();

    foreach (var d in dynObj)
    {
        var properties = d.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var PropertyName = property.Name;
            var PropetyValue = d.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(d, null);
         }
     }
 }
```

`var properties = d.GetType().GetProperties();` always return 0 but I can see at debug that there are properties.

[image]

the CSV file contains this data:

```
Id,Name,Barnd
1,one,abc
2,two,xyz
```

Comment: Try to avoid the `dynamic` type. Its very slow and its not type-safe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reflect over the members of dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634858/how-do-i-reflect-over-the-members-of-dynamic-object)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, `dynamic` type has a `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject` type object while using it. Its same as a `KeyValuePair`type in `C#`.

Following solution will return list of keys and values from `dynamic` type.

```
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    dynObj = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList();

    foreach (var d in dynObj)
    {
        var obj = d as System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject;

        if (obj != null)
        {
            var keys = obj.Select(a => a.Key).ToList();
            var values = obj.Select(a => a.Value).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could also Cast it to `IDictionary<string, object>`

Comment: Thanks you very much Dave!