# View - dynamic model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, view

I am attempting to create a dynamic table in my view that will be dynamically generated depending on the type of model I send to the view. So, I basically have two actions:

```cs
public IActionResult People()
{
        List<Person> lst = new List<Person>();
        // Add data...
        return View("Table", lst);
}

public IActionResult Teams()
{
        List<Team> lst = new List<Team>();
        // Add data...
        return View("Table", lst);
}
```

Now I would like to have the same view that will show a list of people / teams, so that I don't have to duplicate it. My Table.cshtml looks like this:

```
@model List<dynamic>
<table>
    <tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.ElementAt(0).GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            <td>
                @item.Name
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            // foreach (var propValue in item.GetProperties())
            // Get value for each property in the `item`
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

My basic output would be an HTML table corresponding to what is shown below:

```
Id, PersonName, Age
1, John, 24
2, Mike, 32
3, Rick, 27
```

What I have a problem with is dynamically get the value for each property in my model class instance. I don't know how to get the value from the item (there's no such thing as `item.Property(someName).GetValue()`). That way I could send a List (T could be Person, Team, Student, anything) and as a result I would get a `<table>` with Person / Team / Student properties (e.g Id, Name, Age) and values of each of the properties in another `<tr>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634858/how-do-i-reflect-over-the-members-of-dynamic-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reflect over the members of dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634858/how-do-i-reflect-over-the-members-of-dynamic-object)

Comment: Are you able to display the column names ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes to errors when I use `@model List<dynamic>` as model of view.When I change it to `@model dynamic`,it works with below code

```
@model dynamic
@using System.Reflection
@{
    var properties = Model[0].GetType().GetProperties();
}
<table>
    <tr>
        @foreach (var item in properties)
        {
            <td>
                @item.Name
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            @foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
            {
                <td>@p.GetValue(item)</td>
            }
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: This is perfect for when you need something quick and dirty and just need to see all the data in your model that you're testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
@model  List<dynamic>
<table>
    <tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.ElementAt(0).GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            <td>
                @item.Name
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.GetType() == typeof(Person))
        {
            var person = item as Person;

            <tr>
                @person.Name
            </tr>
        }
        if (item.GetType() == typeof(Team)) {

            var team = item as team;

                <tr>
                     @team.Name
               </tr>

        }

    }
</table>
```