# How to get all properties or fields from JObject

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I can't find any solution for my case.I recieve JSON and then I parsed it to my class Instance.In the instance I have property object Model that must be maped from JSON object model.All is good but in this model I don't know how many and which property I can recieve. I want to iterate all props in model and check theirs type.I need this because I want to generate EditForm from model properties.I was tried with

```
foreach(PropertyInfo prop in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
```

but it looks the model is type of NewtonSoft.Json.Linq.JObject.

```
class Instance
{
    public object Model { get; set; }
    public List<Label> Labels { get; set; }
    public List<Instance> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you [check the docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JObjectProperties.htm)? You can use `JObject.Properties` although a better option may be to deserialize the JSON string into a concrete object and make `Instance` a generic class. In any case, change `object` to `JObject`.

Comment: As it so happens `JObject` implements `ICustomTypeDescriptor` so you can use `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj)` to get the properties of an `Instance` or `JObject` in a uniform way, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/TssIx7.  But if you want to get the properties of a POCO such as `Instance` or a `DynamicObject` such as `ExpandoObject` or an entirely custom dynamic object such as `JObject` in a uniform way, see [How do I reflect over the members of dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2634858/3744182).

Comment: Or you could just test to see whether the object is a `JObject` and use `JObject.Properties` as suggested by Panagiotis Kanavos.

Comment: I am not sure how It must to look this in JSON.Because I cant get the property value with name no problem."id": null,
            "caption": "Contactgegevens",
            "concept": "duo-abstr_ContactDetailsTitle",
            "model": [

              { "Geslachtsaanduiding": "Man" },
              { "Voornaam": "Piet" },
              { "Achternaam": "van" },
              { "Dijk": "Bestuursnummer" },
              { "1111": "Straatnaam" },
              { "NL": "Straatweg" },

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem. All is in my JSON file structure. I maked model him like this:

```
model:[ {"key":"someKey","value":"someValue"}]
```