# Provide custom reflection info (PropertyInfo) from DynamicObject

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, system.reflection, dynamicobject

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of [how-do-i-reflect-over-the-members-of-dynamic-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634858/how-do-i-reflect-over-the-members-of-dynamic-object), as I am not interested in finding out the members (I know those), but interested in hooking into the System.Reflection mechanism, so that frameworks/libraries can use my dynamic object.

---

Actual question:

I have objects of type DynamicObject. These objects will be consumed by libraries that operate on members and use reflection. I am wondering if there is a way to achieve the following, i.e. to make reflection return the correct member info (PropertyInfo):

```
  public class TestDO : DynamicObject {
    ...
  }

  typeof(TestDO).getProperty("SomeProp"); // make this not return null
```

I strongly assume it's not possible. In that case, an explanation of why this will never work (Why can't there be such a hook into the reflection system) and potentially an alternative would be nice.

Some ideas are:

- Is it possible to generate the type information at runtime, so that I can just use `typeof(MyJITCreatedType)` (something like byte buddy in the Java world)?
- I have seen ICustomTypeProvider, but have no idea if that can be used (does not even exist in my project currently)?
- Is there some hook in DynamicObject I can implement?

Note:

- I cannot change the way the library consumes my object/uses reflection.
- I can potentially give information about which type is used (i.e. MyJITCreatedType instead of TestDO).
- I know the properties at runtime.
- I can change the implementation of TestDO

Comment: If you know the members at compile time, then why are you using dynamic objects? Dynamics are about doing things at runtime.

Comment: I don't know the members at compile time, I only know them at runtime.

Comment: You will have to [create a class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3862226/880990) at runtime.

Comment: I wish people would stop closing this question.. anyway, creating the class at runtime looks promising.